# Azure data factory V2 copy with stored procedure

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How can I pass the output from the source section of a copy activity as a parameter for a stored procedure.

The stored procedure will be used in the sink section of the same copy activity.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what's the meaning of "*the output from the source section of a copy activity*"? In ADF, only [activities/pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/compare-versions#feature-comparison) have the "output" property. If you want to copy data using the stored procedure in copy activity, this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database#invoking-stored-procedure-for-sql-sink) may give you some reference.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I went to that link and it uses a type. What if I have more than one table to copy, do I have to create a type for all the tables?

Comment: I think so. sqlWriterTableType defines the schema of the table you want to copy. If you need to copy multiple tables, then multiple table types need to be created. thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.